# ElasticSearch Aggregation Combine into an Array

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have some documents that look like this:

```
{"_id": 1, "session_id": "foo", "reply": "yes"}
{"_id": 2, "session_id": "foo", "reply": "no"}
{"_id": 3, "session_id": "foo", "reply": "maybe"}
```

I'd like to run an aggregation that gives me an output like this:

```
{"session_id": "foo", replies: ["yes","no","maybe"] }
```

Is this possible? I want to use the composite aggregation query so I can utilize the paging, because there are millions of records.

I came up with something like this:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs" : {
        "my_buckets": {
            "composite" : {
                "sources" : [
                    { "session_id": { "terms" :       { "field": "sessionId.keyword" } } },
                     { "replies": { "terms": { "field": "reply.keyword" } } }
                ]
            }
        }
     }
}
```

But doesn't quite give the output I'm looking for. I'm using ES 6.4

Thanks